# If statement to use column header name instead of column number?

Tags: excel, vba

In my VBA code in Excel I wrote a bunch of stuff like:

```
If Worksheets("Original Data").Cells(i, 7) <> "" Then 
    'do stuff.
```

The `i` is the iterator for the row number the loop is on. The 7 was* the column number for a specific column, but now in a new "original data" sheet I received this column is in a different place.  Is there a way to replace the 7 with the column header name instead so it doesn't break every time the columns change position?

Comment: You could first loop through the column header (using a for loop) and look for that name. Then note the column number you land on and stick it in a variable. Then use that variable in place of the `7`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use find method to search for the Column header and get the column number

```
Dim ColumnNumber as long

ColumnNumber =  Worksheets("Original Data").cells.Find("Column Name").column
Worksheets("Original Data").Cells(i, ColumnNumber ) <> ""
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks Ronan!
Now, let's say the column names change like Data_Week1, Data_Week2.  Can I include a LIKE in here to still find Data_Week* ??

Comment: Yeah instead , Columnname you can use WildCard , "Data_week*" ,